# Selenium RC is out dated or still in the market after selenium 2.5 release?

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I am writing a training course for Selenium automation testing. I am a bit confused comparing Selenium RC to Selenium2/Webdriver, since the latest release of Selenium2/Webdriver has all of the functionality of Selenium RC. Webdriver is more robust than RC.

Is training on Selenium RC pertinent or will training focused solely on Selenium2/Webdriver be sufficient?

Comment: RC is still used "out there" and could still be pertinent.  But what may be more helpful than a deep dive into RC is conversion from RC to Webdriver.

Comment: Do you have a rationale on why you find it outdated?  I haven't used it, since its not a fit for my environment and WebDriver is, but I've never discounted it for any reason.  Most tools still have a use to someone, it depends on whether you think there is a market for training on it or not

Comment: Why is it OutDated?  Well it's deprecated, in maintenance mode (So nobody is actively working on it) and the current plan is to remove it from the codebase in Selenium 3.0.  Generally Selenium RC is dead, Long live Selenium

Answer (score 2):

Training in Selenium RC would be pertinent.  The percentage of your training on it would be up to you and the information you wish to impart on your class.  [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3619824/whats-the-relationship-between-selenium-rc-and-webdriver) should be a nice resource to compare the differences and see what fits your training agenda best.

Comment: "At the time of writing the Selenium developers are planning on the Selenium-WebDriver API being the future direction for Selenium. Selenium 1 is provided for backwards compatibility. Still, both have strengths and weaknesses which are discussed in the corresponding chapters of this document." (from http://seleniumhq.org/docs/01_introducing_selenium.html#choosing-your-selenium-tool)